# HTML 5 Cache Manifest no longer working in Chrome in IOs

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, webkit, cache-manifest

We have a HTML5 app that need to be work offline as well.

Recently we noticed app is no longer get cached in Chrome 48 in IOS 9.2(ipad)

The app still works(get cached) normally as it used to be with Safari in IOS 9.

I have noticed application cache has been depricated by Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache , but Chrome has not indicated that they have removed support for this and Chorme in other OSs works fine. Can someone suggest how to fix this issue or where to look at.

Comment: I just ran into this problem myself... fortunately, I will only have a small, dedicated user base, so I'll just have to tell them to use Safari...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of WKWebView. See [this Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582192) and [the related WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152490).

Comment: So this mean it is happening because of a WEBkit bug , not because WEB-KIT has deprecated it.

Comment: It means that WKWebView currently provides no way for third-party applications to enable application cache support. Whether that's a bug or not is up to the WebKit developers to decide. What almost certain *is* a bug is that just enough of it is present that it confuses sites that do feature detection to determine whether it's supported.

Comment: WebKit  [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152490) is still in "new" state, need to find an alternative way to tackle applicationCache.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has now fixed in iOS10.